# Varnish 4 not caching

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, centos6, varnish

I am new at working with varnish. I installed it, I think i configured it correctly. In order to test this is what i did:

I created a test page that only has the string "test". 
I went to the page and it has these headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:0
Cache-Control:max-age=120
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:6
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 12 May 2015 19:35:34 GMT
Expires:Tue, 12 May 2015 19:37:34 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Via:1.1 varnish-v4
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
X-Varnish:32829
```

I change the text in the file to "test2"
I go to the page and it shows "test2". I believe it should be showing "test" if it was caching correctly.

I don't have cookies set up or anything, just that. My vcl is very simple:

```
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.


    #This will set up "grace mode".
    set beresp.ttl = 10s;
    set beresp.grace = 1h;


}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Also asked on Unix&Linux; don't do that

Comment: What is the problem with asking in two different forums? The question is related to both

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are good that are sending cookies in your request. Varnish doesn't cache anything with cookies in them. This from the [builtin.vcl for Varnish 4](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/browser/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl?rev=4.0):

> ```
> 47  sub vcl_recv {
> 48        if (req.method == "PRI") {
> 49            /* We do not support SPDY or HTTP/2.0 */
> 50            return (synth(405));
> 51        }
> 52        if (req.method != "GET" &&
> 53          req.method != "HEAD" &&
> 54          req.method != "PUT" &&
> 55          req.method != "POST" &&
> 56          req.method != "TRACE" &&
> 57          req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
> 58          req.method != "DELETE") {
> 59            /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
> 60            return (pipe);
> 61        }
> 62    
> 63        if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
> 64            /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
> 65            return (pass);
> 66        }
> 67        if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
> 68            /* Not cacheable by default */
> 69            return (pass);
> 70        }
> 71        return (hash);
> 72    }
> ```

You need to remove unwanted cookies in your VCL, as shown in [this example from the Varnish website](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCacheCookies)

> #### Removing Set-Cookie from the backend (for a particular path)
>
> In this case, we remove both the Cookie header and the Set-Cookie
>   header for objects under a predefined path. This is quite common for
>   images and similar static content.
>
> ```
> sub vcl_recv {
>     if (req.url ~ "^/images") {
>         unset req.http.cookie;
>     }
> }
>
> sub vcl_backend_response {
>     if (req.url ~ "^/images") {
>         unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
>     }
> }
> ```

If you test with `curl -i URL`, you won't send any cookies, and you if you repeat that more than a second later, you should get an Age header greater than 0.

Comment: You've marked this as correct, but in your question you state *I don't have cookies set up or anything*. Also the headers you show don't reveal any cookies being set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're setting up grace mode correctly. [The varnish book](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Saving_a_request.html) seems to indicate that you should be setting some of this in `vcl_fetch` and perhaps `vcl_recv`.

(I'm not familiar with Varnish, but I hope to be soon).

> #### Core grace mechanisms
>
> A graced object is an object that has expired,
>   but is still kept in cache Grace mode is when Varnish uses a graced
>   object There is more than one way Varnish can end up using a graced
>   object. req.grace defines how long overdue an object can be for
>   Varnish to still consider it for grace mode. beresp.grace defines how
>   long past the beresp.ttl-time Varnish will keep an object req.grace is
>   often modified in vcl_recv based on the state of the backend. When
>   Varnish is in grace mode, it uses an object that has already expired
>   as far as the TTL is concerned. There are several reasons this might
>   happen, one of them being if a backend is marked as bad by a health
>   probe. For Varnish to be able to use a graced object, two things need
>   to happen:
>
> The object needs to still be kept around. This is affected by
>   beresp.grace in vcl_fetch. The VCL has to allow Varnish to use an
>   object as overdue as the one kept around. This is affected by
>   req.grace in vcl_recv. When setting up grace, you will need to modify
>   both vcl_recv and vcl_fetch to use grace effectively. The typical way
>   to use grace is to store an object for several hours past its TTL, but
>   only use it a few seconds after the TTL, except if the backend is
>   sick. We will look more at health checks in a moment, but for now, the
>   following VCL can illustrate a normal setup:
>
> ```
> sub vcl_recv {
>         if (req.backend.healthy) {
>                 set req.grace = 30s;
>         } else {
>                 set req.grace = 24h;
>         }
> }
>
> sub vcl_fetch {
>         set beresp.grace = 24h;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check what headers are being sent to Varnish by Apache. You can also explicitly set the TTL of the content in Varnish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the ttl value to beresp.ttl = 30m; i think varnish has a default ttl value of 120 seconds.

Is the Age: header's value increasing on every next hit?.